# Unable to start Markdown interpreter in Zeppelin Notebook

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When I try to use it I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.markdown.Markdown

With `install-interpreter.sh -l` I do see that md is listed there. So the interpreter is properly installed. I can also select it when creating new notebook as the "default interpreter". However, when I try to evaluate any cell using `%md` I get his class not found exception.

For some reason the interpreter is not included in the class path ... Any suggestion?

Content of interpreter/md/zeppelin-markdown-0.7.1.jar:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/zeppelin/
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/
interpreter-setting.json
META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
META-INF/LICENSE
META-INF/NOTICE
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/Markdown$1.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/Markdown$MarkdownParserType$1.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/Markdown$MarkdownParserType$2.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/Markdown$MarkdownParserType.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/Markdown.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/Markdown4jParser.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/MarkdownParser.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/ParamVar.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/PegdownParser.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/PegdownWebSequencelPlugin.class
org/apache/zeppelin/markdown/PegdownYumlPlugin.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/org.apache.zeppelin/
META-INF/maven/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-markdown/
META-INF/maven/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-markdown/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-markdown/pom.properties
```

Comment: What is version of Zeppelin you are using?

Comment: Latest 7.1 I think

Comment: I downloaded bin-0.7.1 and Executed `%md` successfully with JDK 1.7 and 1.8 (tested twice). Could you run `vi interpreter/md/zeppelin-markdown-0.7.1.jar` and share the result?

Comment: Thank you @1ambda. Let me do that as soon as possible.

Comment: @1ambda I just updated it. Yea, so everything seems to be there. I am wondering if something happened in my interpreter.json file while I was editing that around. For some reason, this jar doesn't get into the classpath ...

Comment: Let's remove inerpreter.json and restart Zeppelin. Then, zeppelin will restore original file. If interpreter.json ks problem, we can fix it like that.

Comment: I noticed that they were quite a lot kind of "zombie" zeppelin processes running on my machine. After killing them, it seems that this problem went away ... Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the markdown interpreter install , you just need to create a new Interpreter binding for the markdown.

To create a new binding for markdown

1. Click the settings button
   [Binding Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d72lM.png)
2. Click on the interpreter menu
   [Interpreter menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rngEj.png)
3. Click on the create buttom
   [Create button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uO3G.png)
4. Give Interpreter name as md and Interpreter group as md then save 
   [Adding binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRHR4.png)
5. Go back to the notebook and add md binding to notebook and save [Adding interpreter to notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys8Oy.png)
6. Now %md should start your markdown Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that they were quite a lot "zombie" Zeppelin processes running on my machine. After killing them, it seems that this problem went away.